# Find k so that there is only one solution for set of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find k so that there is only one solution for set of equations, and k also satisfy **$x1+x3=k+5$**
The set of equations:
$$x1+x2+kx3=k$$
$$kx2=k$$
$$kx1+x2+x3=1$$

I remember we solved similar exercises, but I kind of confused how to procced...

My way of solution, by writing in matrix form:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &k  &k \\ 
 0& k &0  &k \\ 
 k& 1 &1  &1 
\end{pmatrix}r3-kr1\rightarrow r3$

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &k  &k \\ 
 0& k &0  &k \\ 
 0& 1-k &1 -k^2 &1-k^2 
\end{pmatrix}kr3-r2(1-k)\rightarrow r3$

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &k  &k \\ 
 0& k &0  &k \\ 
 0& 0 &k(1-k^2) &k(1-k^2)-k(1-k)=-k^3+k^2 
\end{pmatrix}$

I've written the 4th column as the solution because I don't know how to add the dividing line.

after reaching the reduced form, I have no clue how the condition: $x1+x3=k+5$
helps for solution.

how do I continue?

***answer:*** $k\neq 0,1$

Comment: Please use the `_` to make subscripts in equations, like $x_1$ rather than $x1$, which is a sore to the eye and makes reading difficult.

Comment: The additional condition just makes this a system of four equations instead of three.

Answer (score 1):

If $k=0$, the second of your equations (in your final form) is just $0=0$. This is a trivial equation, and therefore you can forget it. What's left is a system of two linear equations in three unknows. Such a system either has no solutions or it has infinitely many.

Suppose now that $k=1$. Then what I wrote above about the second equation holds if “second” gets replaced by “third”.

In the remaining cases, there is one and only one solution. You get from your system that$$x_3=\frac{-k^3+k^2}{k(1-k^2)},$$and that $x_2=1$. Finally, from this information and from the fact that $x_1+x_2+kx_3=k$, you get the value of $x_1$.